# How can I work out what values to use for TListBox.ScrollWidth?

Tags: delphi, winapi

I'm trying to work out how to set `ScrollWidth` on a `TListBox` to control the horizontal scroll bar. Here's my first attempt:

```
program ListBoxSizing;

uses
  Math, Forms, StdCtrls;

var
  Form: TForm;
  ListBox: TListBox;

procedure BuildForm;
begin
  //Form.Font.Size := 9;
  Form.ClientWidth := 200;
  Form.ClientHeight := 100;
  ListBox := TListBox.Create(Form);
  ListBox.Parent := Form;
  ListBox.SetBounds(0, 0, Form.ClientWidth, Form.ClientHeight);
  ListBox.Items.Add('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ');
end;

procedure SetScrollWidth;
var
  i, MaxWidth: Integer;
begin
  MaxWidth := -1;
  for i := 0 to ListBox.Items.Count-1 do
    MaxWidth := Max(MaxWidth, ListBox.Canvas.TextWidth(ListBox.Items[i]));
  if MaxWidth<>-1 then
    ListBox.ScrollWidth := MaxWidth;
end;

begin
  Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
  Application.CreateForm(TForm, Form);
  BuildForm;
  SetScrollWidth;
  Application.Run;
end.
```

This is how the result looks with the horizontal scroll bar moved as far right as possible:

[image]

Notice how the last part of the final character has been chopped off.

Now, if we uncomment the line that changes the form's font size, it looks like this:

[image]

Now, it seems that the change to font size hasn't been accounted for in the subsequent calls to `TextWidth`.

So, my question is, what code do I need to use to be able to set `ScrollWidth` accurately, based on the current contents of the list box.

Comment: Possible work around if no solution presents itself (I am sure you already thought of it): if the listbox's canvas isn't updated with the font changes, why not use an off screen canvas or some such to call textwidth on?

Comment: This is a meta comment directed at all you Delphi answerers out there. Both answers here were helpful and steered me to the solution. But both answers were 100% code. So I really had to struggle to understand what the real issues were. The Width-ClientWidth issue is obvious and needs little explanation. But setting `ListBox.Canvas.Font` outside of paint events is subtle and deserves at least paragraph of explanation. I think that quite often answers would be much improved if they contained more explanatory prose. In my opinion, we in the Delphi tag produce too many code only answers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
procedure SetScrollWidth;
var
  I, MaxWidth: Integer;
begin
  MaxWidth := -1;
  // assign control's font to canvas
  ListBox.Canvas.Font := ListBox.Font;
  for I := 0 to ListBox.Items.Count - 1 do
    MaxWidth := Max(MaxWidth, ListBox.Canvas.TextWidth(ListBox.Items[I]));
  // consider non-client area
  if MaxWidth <> -1 then
    ListBox.ScrollWidth := MaxWidth + ListBox.Width - ListBox.ClientWidth;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks. Forcing the list box font to be the form font is helpful. That will happen eventually, through UseParentFont, but I guess my code here is somehow bypassing that.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Note that I'm assigning listbox's font to listbox's canvas (this is not done automatically).

Comment: Ah, now I fully understand the significance of `ListBox.Canvas.Font := ListBox.Font`. If you are outside a paint event then you have to make that assignment yourself. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

```
program Project2;

uses
  Math, Forms, StdCtrls,Windows,Graphics;

var
  Form: TForm;
  ListBox: TListBox;

procedure BuildForm;
begin
  //Form.Font.Size := 9;
  Form.ClientWidth := 200;
  Form.ClientHeight := 100;
  ListBox := TListBox.Create(Form);
  ListBox.Parent := Form;
  Listbox.Font.Size := 40;
  ListBox.SetBounds(0, 0, Form.ClientWidth, Form.ClientHeight);
  ListBox.Items.Add('ABCDEFGXXXXXXXXXXXXOXOXYQASEOOWW');
  ListBox.Items.Add('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ');
  ListBox.Items.Add('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ111111111111111111111111111111111111111O');

end;

function GetRealFontWidth(fnt: TFont; const text:string): Integer;
var
   dc: hdc;
   tsize : Windows.TSize;
   oldObj : Cardinal;
begin
   dc := GetDC(0);
   oldObj := SelectObject(DC, fnt.Handle);
   GetTextExtentPoint32(dc, PChar(text), Length(text), tsize);
   SelectObject(DC, oldObj);
   ReleaseDC(0, DC);
   Result := tsize.cx;
end;

procedure SetScrollWidth;
var
  i, MaxWidth: Integer;
begin
  MaxWidth := -1;
  for i := 0 to ListBox.Items.Count-1 do
    MaxWidth := Max(MaxWidth, GetRealFontWidth (ListBox.Font,ListBox.Items[i]));
  if MaxWidth<>-1 then
    ListBox.ScrollWidth := MaxWidth + 4;
end;

begin
  Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
  Application.CreateForm(TForm, Form);
  BuildForm;
  SetScrollWidth;
  Application.Run;
end.
```

Comment: Thank you. That deals with the second problem, but leaves the first problem. I'm still getting the final character truncated. I'd guess because there is some internal margin of the control that needs to be accounted for. It would be nice to be able to use `TCanvas` for this rather than hacking around with DCs. There surely must be a way to get the canvas to load the appropriate font.

Comment: I think, using Form.Canvas.TextWidth instead of ListBox.Canvas.TextWidth gives the same effect as GetRealFontWidth

Comment: @SimaWB,did you see "Listbox.Font.Size := 40;" in the test

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I agree with your guess of some internal margin, this was my first attempt with adding 4, before I found the texwidth problem

Comment: Do you need to re-select the previous font into the DC after you are done with it? That is, do you need to undo the `SelectObject` before calling `ReleaseDC`?

Comment: Thanks again for the answer it really helped. I accepted @TOndrej's answer because it picked up the Width-ClientWidth issue. The other issue, getting text width correct is cleaner in the other answer too. It's exactly equivalent to your approach, but simpler.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan agree ... but there is an interesting differ between TOndrej's and mine, with e.g. Font.Size=40 (ListBox.Width - ListBox.ClientWidth is increasing to more than 4, which seems to be the space really needed)

Comment: Bonus points for the inventive way to post a self-contained GUI example with just a single .dpr

Comment: @Wouter Thanks. I wanted to make it as easy as possible for the answerers to run exactly the same code as me.