# Delphi - if jump outside case

Tags: delphi

I use this code to test pressing 3 letters at the same time but `IF` jump outside `case`!

```
....
private
FValidKeyCombo: boolean
....

procedure MyForm.FormKeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  if FValidKeyCombo and (Shift = [ssAlt]) then
    case Key of
      Ord('N'): //New
        if (GetKeyState(Ord('C')) and $80) = $80 then 
          btn1.OnClick(nil)

        else if (GetKeyState(Ord('T')) and $80) = $80 then 
          btn2.OnClick(nil)

        else if (GetKeyState(Ord('Q')) and $80) = $80 then 
          btn3.OnClick(nil)

        else if (GetKeyState(Ord('W')) and $80) = $80 then 
          btn3.OnClick(nil);

     Ord('E'): //New
        if (GetKeyState(Ord('C')) and $80) = $80 then 
          btn1.OnClick(nil)

        else if (GetKeyState(Ord('T')) and $80) = $80 then //<-- after this line if jump to line 30!! why ???
          btn2.OnClick(nil)

        else if (GetKeyState(Ord('Q')) and $80) = $80 then 
          btn3.OnClick(nil)

        else if (GetKeyState(Ord('W')) and $80) = $80 then 
          btn3.OnClick(nil);

  end; //case Key of

{This is line 30}  FValidKeyCombo := (Shift = [ssAlt]) and (Key in [Ord('C'), Ord('T'), Ord('Q'), Ord('W')]);
end;

procedure MyForm.FormKeyUp(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  FValidKeyCombo := False;
end;
```

as commented in code `If` jump to the line 30 that set `FValidKeyCombo` value 
this happen when I press on Alt+W+E !! why ??

Comment: It's the next line that's after the case.., naturally it runs. Exit from the 'if' if you don't like it. 'else if .... then begin btnclick exit end'.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: And what you expect to happen?

Comment: Re edit: When you press Alt+W+E, the 'W' case runs on the last round and then execution continues with the line you marked with 30. Why shouldn't it? It's the line that comes after the case.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz thanks for the follow up......I know it is normal after case to go to line 30 but the problem it never test for 'W', after testing for 'T' it goes to line 30..do you know why ?

Comment: @Well - I copy/pasted your code and when I press Alt+W+E, in that order, the 'W' case runs, i.e. I cannot duplicate that. Don't know if it's related, but in general most of the keyboards have problems with simultaneously pressed multiple keys, thought I'd think 2 keys with a modifier shouldn't be a problem. This can only be relevant if btn2 is clicking of course..

Comment: @SertacAkyuz will try to use another keyboard and test that although when I press Alt+C+E it work normally !!

Comment: tried with another keyboard on different PC does not work either!! what logical reason can cause this problem ??!!

Comment: You will need to face up to the fact that keyboards don't do what you want them to do.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan dont know what you mean here.

Comment: You want your keyboard to detect multiple keys pressed simultaneously. Keyboards cannot do that.

Comment: @David oh yes I suspected that but why the first and second IF work.

Comment: Keyboards don't do what you want them too. In time you'll accept that. As an aside, don't call `OnClick` event handlers. Call the `Click` method if you must fake a click.

Comment: @David...ok then I will change code to use one key with Alt seems a ghosting problem....thanks about the click hint.

Comment: FWIW, you code works fine on my keyboard. I can hold down ALT, then W, then E, and the correct leg of the case/if combo is executed.

Comment: What keyboard you have David ? I have now ordinary one but will buy a mechanical soon.

Comment: I have daskeyboard. And a nice mechanical Cherry at work. What are you actually trying to do? It sounds odd. Perhaps you've not got the right solution yet to whatever the problem is.

Comment: @David just building shortcut system to open many forms nothing fancy....I tested something and it is very strange: just tried to compile the same code on Delphi XE3 and it work normally !! but in my IDE of Delphi 2010 it does not !!......do you have Delphi 2010 to confirm ?

Comment: Works fine on all versions of Delphi. I expect you are running different code. You've copied it incorrectly. For a start you should be able to cut this down to a single short complete compilable sample. Then you can paste it into the question and we can be 100% sure we are all running the same code. My question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13643698/how-can-i-work-out-what-values-to-use-for-tlistbox-scrollwidth shows how to do that

Comment: You would be better using compound accelerators like Office. They work on all keyboards.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan you tested on all Delphi versions for me!! that is so cool! you was right there is some other code I could not post you know because of NDA....fixed now.....my deep respect and thanks.

Comment: I didn't test on all versions. But your code is not version specific. It will work the same way on all versions.

Comment: was thinking some sort of compiler bug....appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

Your code works OK.

My guess is you may have *by accident* introduced a `;` in between the `btn2.OnClick()` and the next `else` statement, terminating your `if` statement. It Compiles because the `case` statement also can have a `else` part and you're already at the last value of the case.

For this, I always surround complex code in a **`begin/end`** pair, it cost nothing, but adds a lot of clarity to the code.

For example, I changed your code to this:

```
procedure TForm1.FormKeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word;
  Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  if FValidKeyCombo and (Shift = [ssAlt]) then
  begin
    case Key of
      Ord('N'): //New
        begin
          if (GetKeyState(Ord('C')) and $80) = $80 then
            btn1.OnClick(nil)
          else if (GetKeyState(Ord('T')) and $80) = $80 then
            btn2.OnClick(nil)
          else if (GetKeyState(Ord('Q')) and $80) = $80 then
            btn3.OnClick(nil)
          else if (GetKeyState(Ord('W')) and $80) = $80 then
            btn3.OnClick(nil);
        end;
     Ord('E'): //New
       begin
        if (GetKeyState(Ord('C')) and $80) = $80 then
          btn1.OnClick(nil)
        else if (GetKeyState(Ord('T')) and $80) = $80 then
          btn2.OnClick(nil) //a ; here now produces a compiler error
        else if (GetKeyState(Ord('Q')) and $80) = $80 then
          btn3.OnClick(nil)
        else if (GetKeyState(Ord('W')) and $80) = $80 then
          btn3.OnClick(nil);
       end;
    end; //case Key of
  end;
  FValidKeyCombo := (Shift = [ssAlt]) and (Key in [Ord('C'), Ord('T'), Ord('Q'), Ord('W')]);
end;
```

Comment: thanks my friend but no extra ; and I tried begin...end same result !!

Comment: @David, I was guessing, the code is in fact the same, and my answer states why.